# Create a button with rounded corners

Tags: c#, winforms, button, rounded-corners

i need some help with creating a button with rounded corners.

I just read this post:
[C# How to Add Round Corner to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718619/c-sharp-how-to-add-round-corner-to-button)

But i don't know what to do with this code.
can somebody help me please.

Comment: I added an explanation of extension methods as well, see my edit.  They should be very easy to research once you know what they are called, but let me know if something isnt clear.  good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the comments in the answer.  You implement those methods like this:

```
myGraphic.DrawRoundedRectangle(Color.Blue, btnBG, 10, RoundedCorners.All);
```

`btnBG` is declared

```
Rectangle btnBG = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
```

These methods are implemented as extension methods.  You can tell by the first param in the method being `this`.

Its usually best to put these methods into their own static class in the namespace that you want to use them.  In this case, your UI namespace.

Comment: ok, thank you for your fast answer.
but i still don't get it
i have a button named "button1" and where can i declare or implement the button to the rest of the code, but this code "myButton.DrawRoundedRectangle(Color.Blue, btnBG, 10, RoundedCorners.All);" does not realy work                                i will send your my code tomorrow because today i can't answer       but maybe you now a solution for this problem

Comment: Ok, this example assumes that you have dropped a button called `myButton` on to your form.  I'll change the example to reflect your code.