# How can I make round edge of button, textbox, form and groupbox in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, groupbox

I want to make my button, form, textbox and groupbox a bit round from edges. I tried this,

```
GraphicsPath mygp = new GraphicsPath();
Graphics mygr = this.CreateGraphics(); 
Pen myp = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

mygp.AddArc(400, 10, 30, 30, 180, 90);

mygp.AddArc(600, 10, 30, 30, 270, 90);
mygp.AddArc(600, 200, 30, 30, 0, 90);
mygp.AddArc(400, 200, 30, 30, 90, 90);
mygr.FillPath(Brushes.Black, mygp);
mygr.DrawPath(myp, mygp);
```

it makes a block with round edges. But I want my button etc to have rounded edge.

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718619/c-sharp-how-to-add-round-corner-to-button

Comment: WinForms creates a window handle for every control, and window handles are rectangular. Rounded corners are possible, but they're not easy to do well. If you want odd-shaped buttons (and want them to look good), you're much better off using WPF instead of WinForms. If you really need WinForms for some reason, look into third-party libraries; some of them are skinnable and might allow this kind of customization.

Comment: You're running into problems early. It's not as simple as just creating a graphics path...you will need to redraw the entire control. I would suggest either invest a HELL of a lot of time in GDI / GDI+ (which is becoming deprecated), or...move to WPF which will make your life a lot simpler!

Comment: @series0ne Can you please explain me what is WPF? Actually I am a beginner in c#.

Comment: @user3193652 WPF stands for Windows Presentation Foundation. It is Microsoft's new way to build Windows GUI applications. Based on DirectX graphics as opposed to GDI/GDI+ If you are new to C#, then DEFINITELY go for WPF, because otherwise, the learning curve transition from Windows Forms to WPF will be a nightmare! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user3193652, I have asked questions (similar to yours) about rounded rectangles in C#, and also I have a question which addresses the transition from Windows Forms to WPF. Check out my profile!

Comment: Pretty difficult to get good advice from WPF programmers.  It is as simple as just creating a GraphicsPath.  Create a Region from it, assign the button's Region property.

Comment: I am making an assignment on courier service. And I just wanted it to be more cute with round edges, but I guess, it is very difficult for me. but still thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most appropreate way is to write your code in OnPaint event which enables you draw the button by yourself. In following link you will find a good solution using same kind of approach.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15730/RoundButton-Windows-Control-Ever-Decreasing-Circle