# How to add radius to all buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I was searching the internet and I couldn't find a solution of how to add corner radius to all buttons in form or solution.

I tried adding `Drawing` into form but that works only for selected buttons.
Is there a solution in `Designer` I could use to make this work as it should?

Comment: wpf or winforms or asp.net or?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's winforms, just added a new tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718619/c-sharp-how-to-add-round-corner-to-button  or  http://dotnetrix.co.uk/button.htm

Comment: @JohnBustos thank you for your response, but I am not really familiar with C# at all so I guess I can't translate that code to vb.net, also I am not into using third-party .dll`s in my code since in most of time I am not able to change it as I want it to be.

Comment: @Hoh, did you look at the second link? Look at the last example he gives... MIGHT give you what you're looking for (and it's in VB too)

Comment: Yeah, that actually did helped.  
Write this as your answer so I can mark it, please.
Thanks a lot